# solution for drupal collaboration using version control system

Tags: svn, drupal, collaboration

I just started working with Drupal for a while and decided to use this CMS to build a website. There are other developers who r working with me on this so we need some means to collaborate effectively. Usually, I'm used to using SVN for team work but it seems that it is quite difficult to use SVN for Drupal because it stores a lot of configuration in the database. Since each of us has ours own local database (may have different settings), it is quite hard to synchronize everything because if we only commit and update Drupal code from the common repo, drupal code might not match the data stored in each person's database. Could you guys provide me with some advices or best practices on this problem.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Subjective questions like this are off-topic here: voting to migrate to [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Mark Trapp - How to use version control in a Drupal project may be really difficult to answer but it's by no means subjective.

Comment: @Mark Trapp - this is very relevant for Drupal development and fair game IMHO

Comment: @Álvaro @jpstrikesback Best practices questions are subjectively guided and aren't the domain of Stack Overflow. Check out [Stack Overflow's FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [Programmers.SE's FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there
That question has also stumpled me a bit, or in general, just how to easily migrate from test to production, etc.
You can extract all the confiuration items, and store them in SVN (or any similar tool), and thereby share the configuration settings.
You mainly have to use the Features module, as to bundle your configurations and Content types etc. into clusteres of fetures.
A more detailed description and approach can be found here:
[Managing and deploying configuration with exportables and the Features module](http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/managing-and-deploying-configuration-exportables-and-features-module)

It gives a very good idea on how to do this, and collaborate.